# Following Apple's instructions for Settings.bundle

Tags: swift

I have followed the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW4) to the letter.

What I do not understand in the instructions is how to get the settings page to show in a view/view controller. I just cannot get the settings page to display.

Can anyone clarify the instructions a bit?

Comment: Could you please provide code that you have tried

Comment: I'm not sure it's what you want. The settings bundle is for use in the system Settings app. When you open the Settings app on your phone, when you tap on your app's name your settings bundle will show there.

Comment: I am so dumb. I thought I was adding a settings page to my app, not adding options to configure from the Settings app on the phone. It was working, and I did not even know it :-(

Comment: That doesn't make you dumb at all, it just means you misunderstood. Don't be so hard on yourself.

Comment: You are definitely not dumb.  You learnt something.  Doing something wrong and learning from it can often be much better than doing something correct the first time from which you then learn nothing.  I also don't understand the downvote as it appears a perfectly valid question to ask to me.